# Editing multi-line text in address book fields

Tags: contacts

I often have multi-line text in my address book, in fields such as notes or the first line of the address.

Editing this seems near-impossible, as the text entry field only shows one line at a time.

Is there any way to cursor through the multiple lines of text so I can edit it easily?

The phone in question is an HTC Desire S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get an on-screen keyboard with arrow keys, such as [Hacker's keyboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard). I use it as a secondary input method, it's not so suitable to all situations but can quickly be switched from the long-press menu.